# How come the non-abelian property is lost in this isomorphism of quaternions?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Identify $q \in \mathbb{H}$ by $q \iff \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -\overline{b} & \overline{a} \end{pmatrix}$ where $a = t + ix$ and $b = (y + zi)j$.

I just noticed that if $q = j$ for example, then $q \iff \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}.$ But notice if I conjugate $e^{i\phi_1} j e^{-i\phi_2} = -e^{i(\phi_1 + \phi_2)}j$. Yet if I do the matrix multiplication, I get  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & e^{i(\phi_1 - \phi_2)} \\ -e^{i(\phi_2 - \phi_1)} & 0 .\end{pmatrix}

**How come the non-abelian property is lost in this isomorphism of quaternions?**

Comment: Just be more careful... things are ok here...

Comment: @paulgarrett, no they aren't.

Comment: Well, in any case, matrix exponentiation does _not_ satisfy $e^{A+B}=e^A\cdot e^B$, so a general invocation of that (false) "property" does not actually generate any paradox. Is this conceivably the issue?

Comment: @Mark, yes that's a typo on my part. let me make 1 quick edit

Comment: @paulgarrett, no $i \phi$ is not a matrix. My issue is that I am getting $e^{i(\phi_2-\phi_1}j$ instead of $e^{i(\phi_2 + \phi_1)}j$

Comment: Is there a typo in the last displayed matrix? One exponent is the negative of the other (and that will *not* happen with matrix multiplication).

Comment: @SteveD, deleted, but issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it’s too long.

First, you’re not doing a “conjugation”. Second, after the word “conjugate”, I get
$$
e^{i\phi_1}je^{-i\phi_2}=e^{i(\phi_1+\phi_2)}j\,.
$$
Third, I don’t believe you did your matrix multiplication correctly. To make make things easy for myself, I’m going to write $\cos\phi_1=c_1$, $\sin\phi_1=s_1$, similarly for $\phi_2$, as well as $\cos(\phi_1+\phi_2)=c$, $\sin(\phi_1+\phi_2)=s$. Then my matrix computation goes:
\begin{align}
&\pmatrix{c_1+is_1&0\\0&c_1-is_1}
\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
\pmatrix{c_2-is_2&0\\0&c_2+is_2}\\
&=\pmatrix{c_1+is_1&0\\0&c_1-is_1}
\pmatrix{0&c_2+is_2\\-c_2+is_2&0}\\
&=\pmatrix{0&c_1c_2-s_1s_2+i(c_1s_2+c_2s_1)\\-c_1c_2+s_1s_2+i(c_1s_2+c_2s_1)&0}\\
&=\pmatrix{0&c+is\\-c+is&0}=\pmatrix{c+is&0\\0&c-is}j\,,
\end{align}
which is exactly what the other computation gave.

Fourth, I don’t see how your computation, if done correctly, would have said anything in particular about commutativity. If you had had $\phi_1=\phi_2$, then the computation would have been a conjugation, and you would have found that $e^{i\phi}$ conjugates $j$ into $e^{2i\phi}j$, not particularly surprising.

Comment: [WolframAlpah agrees with my computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Bexp%5Bix_1%5D,0%7D,+%7B0,+exp%5Bix_2%5D+%7D+%7D.%7B+%7B+0,1%7D,+%7B-1,0%7D%7D.%7B%7Bexp%5B-ix_1%5D,0%7D,+%7B0,+exp%5B-ix_2%5D+%7D+%7D)

Comment: Nvm, I multipled the objects $e^{i\theta} \in Sp(1)$ with objects in $M_2(C)$. The isomoprhism of $e^{i\theta} \leftrightarrow$ is given by the trignometric matrix you have written.

Comment: Maybe I should explain that although I “know” that you can look at the quaternions as special matrices over $\Bbb C$, I *always* do my computations in the four-dimensional $\Bbb R$-space with basis $\{1,i,j,k\}$ and with the commutations relations that you know and love. So I needed to write things out carefully for myself to see what was going on.

Comment: @jacobsmith, I just looked at your Wolframite. Your error was in the way you set up the mx mult for him. What you set up does not represent the multiplication you set for yourself at the outset.